# Integrating coffee script and play framework on IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework, coffeescript

I was following play tutorial- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNCerkVyQdc , so created one coffee script called index.coffee. When I run the app, I see index.js missing on browser's console, what is the problem? do I need to install node.js? doesn't that come default with activator? I feel somewhere IntelliJ idea is not converting to to js when I run it/ debug it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the coffeescript plugin in your plugins.sbt file:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
```

When compiling or running, you should see this on the console:

```
[info] CoffeeScript compiling on 1 source(s)
```